# SQL Query for Counting Values in a Set Column

Tags: sql, set, grouping

I dont know if this is possible with one query, but here goes:

I have a column that is a set datatype.  I want to select a count of each possible value of the set.  So I have:

row 1 set column value: 'opt 1','opt 2'

row 2 set column value: 'opt 1', 'opt 3'

row 3 set column value: 'opt 3','opt 4','opt 2'

I need a query that will produce a structure similar to (doesnt have to be exactly this, just a count for each possible value of the set):

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        'value'=>'opt 1',
        'count'=> 2
    ),
    [1] => Array(
        'value'=>'opt 2',
        'count' => 2
    ),
    [2] => Array(
        'value'=>'opt 3',
        'count' => 2
    ),
    [3] => Array(
        'value'=>'opt 4',
        'count' => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: what type of sql database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your SET column is a bitmap, you could setup a query like this:

```
SELECT count(NULLIF(columnName & 1,0)) as Count1stVal,
       count(NULLIF(columnName & 2,0)) as Count2ndVal,
       count(NULLIF(columnName & 4,0)) as Count3rdVal,
       count(NULLIF(columnName & 8,0)) as Count4thVal,
```

...

Comment: yessir thats the ticket thank you, what is going on in this query?

Comment: @chris ... what it does? have a look at the manual how data in a set column is represented ... it's a bitmap so your first possible value in the set is mapped to the lowest bit ... number two goes to bit number two ... etc... so all this does is: look at the bit position, and count it only if that bit was 1

Comment: +1 - I suppose it doesn't matter that there's not really a generalized solution, because the set columns are predefined anyways.

Comment: @colinmarc ... i don't think a generalized solution is possible in one step ... you would have to get the set definition for that column (one query) and dynamically generate your actual query (second query) ... but i can't see how to do this nicely in only one statement ... the reason for that might be the fact that it is 3:35 AM here ... ;)

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 - definitely two queries, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question entirely, but if you're suggesting a table with a column that has values, and you want your query to output two columns, one being the value, and the second being the number of occurrences in the table for that value, you would do:

```
    SELECT column, count(column)
    FROM table
    GROUP BY column
    ORDER BY column;
```